# VBA text box input mask

Tags: ms-access, vba, syntax, validation

I have two validation for date and time as below in text boxes:

```
00/00\ 00:00;0;0;_
```

It will take (dd/mm hh:mm) and works fine

But sometimes i put

34/34 56:78 it will take , But it shouldn't

Date sholdnot go beyond 31, month 12 time 24 and minute 59

Please help

Comment: Is this a date instant or a duration e.g. what about if they enter 31/02 and you find you can't convert it to 31st February for any given year?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem with a Credit Card expiration date field yesterday. I'd stupidly changed 00/0000 as input mask to 00/00, and encountered the problem you're having. the issue is that if the second pair of digits is a valid date, it will be interpreted as a date and the current year will be supplied tacitly. Thus, if you enter:

```
  06/09
```

for Jun 2009, it will be stored as:

```
  06/09/2009
```

On the other hand, if you enter:

```
  06/34
```

it will be interpreted as

```
  06/01/1934
```

So far as I can see, the only way for you to do what you want is to use a 4-digit year.

Answer (score 0):

validate the date using [`IsDate()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isdate.php)

```
Public Function ValidateDate(input As String) As Boolean    

    ValidateDate = IsDate(input)

End Function
```

this returns a boolean value, True if the input is a valid date string, False if it isn't. The maximum values are

> Day: 31
>
> Month: 12
>
> Hour: 23
>
> Min: 59
>
> Sec: 59

Comment: Sorry i edited my question ; this is an input mask not validation

Comment: is that an input mask on the table field or on the textbox on the form? You will still need some form of validation on the form and can put this function in the On Exit event

Comment: Thanks for response; i only need input mask no validation 
Is it possible to restrict this with input mask?

Answer (score 0):

Input masks in Access cannot be restricted to ranges of values, like with a RegExp. Only way to do this is use some validation (which can be done on a keypress if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

Approach the problem differently. Give the user a calendar to pick from. You could use something like Allen Browne's [Popup Calendar](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-51.html)

Disable and lock the text field and you can guarantee that the format is correct.