# Validation Problem in vba text box

Tags: ms-access, vba, syntax, validation

I want to validate a text box

where the user enters the date in format  dd/mm

and time hh/mm

in the same text box

how to do this?

Comment: Why are you posting the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135609/vba-text-box-input-mask

Comment: Is this a date instant or a duration e.g. what about if they enter 31/02 and you find you can't convert it to 31st February for any given year?

Comment: This is almost identical to your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135609/vba-text-box-input-mask/1138234#1138234

Comment: See my answer in the other instance of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135609/vba-text-box-input-mask/1138234#1138234 , specifically, require a 4-digit year and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to achieve this. There are a couple of complicated ways.

You can make the control unbound, then write a handler for the After Update event of the control. In this handler, you will need to validate the user's entry, create a date value from the entry (presumably defaulting the year to the current year), and assign that value to the field storing the date. In addition, you will need an OnCurrent event on the form, where you will set the value of the unbound control to be the appropriately-formatted text version of the date of the current record.

Note that this method won't work in a Continuous form, only on a Single Form.